# how to get video thumbnail in c#?

Tags: c#, video, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to show a list of videos on my website. For this I want to a show video thumbnail in a list and on click of that thumbnail I will play video. My question is, is there any way to get first frame/thumbnail of a video? I am using asp.net MVC and C#.

I cannot use ffmpeg because I cannot run other executables in the Azure account/role I have chosen.

Comment: The duplicate solution does use ffmpeg in the background, but I don't see a problem with Azure hosting. If you have problems getting it to work in Azure, that might be worth another question.

Comment: @nvoigt for ffmpeg we need to add virtual machine to run exe. exe not run on cloud so don't want to use ffmpeg. so do not mark it duplicate

Comment: Ok, please do add those requirements to your question. You cannot use ffmpeg *because you cannot run other executables* in the Azure account/role you have chosen. Azure is a set of cloud services and some do allow running executables.